# Playbook tags works when executed with ansible-playbook command but not in AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have an issue where Ansible tags work in my machine, but not when using AWX. The tags are not identified and the output is like this:

```
PLAYBOOK: main.yml *************************************************************
Positional arguments: main.yml
verbosity: 4
remote_user: root
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('mytag',)
inventory: ('/tmp/awx_7826_15vdhwft/tmp3kncv6f3',)
subset: bnso9910
extra_vars: ('@/tmp/awx_7826_15vdhwft/env/extravars',)
forks: 20
1 plays in main.yml
```

The tag is correct and yet it does not seem to run in AWX. Any ideas?

I tried the code on my machine and it works.

Comment: `tags: ('mytag',)` indeed shows you passed `mytag` to the playbook, now, are you sure _main.yml_ does contains the tag? On the AWX server copy as well?

Comment: yes I'm sure that the code is updated with the tags